# How to display Language Picker for all users in Salesforce Communities

Tags: lightning-experience, customer-community

I'm trying to get the language picker available not only for guest users. Is this possible?
Once a user logs in they should still be able to change languages from the picker but it disappears from view once they logged in.
Any way this can be fixed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Guest User does not have a user profile, and can not set his/her language, a logged in user can change his locale settings, so we would not need the language picker.

At least that is how Salesforce thinks....

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.community_templates.meta/community_templates/rss_language_picker.htm

https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter16/release-notes/rss_language_picker.htm

So make sure a logged in user can change their locale settings.